# How can I fire an asp.net button event via jquery or java script?

Tags: c#, jquery

I want when I click on "Doit" string it fire my asp.net button .

This is my "DoIt"

```
<a id="" href="#"">Doit</a>
```

And my asp.net button event is :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("rightclick.aspx");
}
```

How can I do this ? Please help me ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Button1` already exists, have such code:

```
<a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click(); return false;">Doit</a>
```

This will "auto click" the button thus trigger any server side code handling its click.

Comment: Cheers @Persian feel free to Accept the answer by clicking the V icon to the left. :)

Comment: hi, will it load the page??

Comment: @Neel load what page? When clicked, it will simply be the same as clicking Button1, which in the OP's example redirects to a different page when clicked. Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: suppose i have a button in my aspx page which is hidden and i trigger its click event from js file and it has server side method but i dnt want to load whole page..i guess i need update panel. anyother approach?

Comment: @Neel so having it triggered like that is totally not relevant. You need AJAX, and there are many ways to use AJAX, UpdatePanel is one way, jQuery also got good support for AJAX.

Comment: yes i have thought about that as well but i have never used ajax call for server side methods of a user control. it works the same way it does for web service?

Comment: @Neel sounds like you'll be most comfortable with  Page Method - look for this in Google and surely you'll find tons of examples. Good luck!

Comment: yeah thanx, btw i just remembered we have talked before..ur that toilet paper guy i guess :))

Comment: @Neel lol, guess you refer to my famous question on Travel.SE? Weird, can't see you have account there... or was there something else with toilet paper... ?

Comment: yeah right i dont have account there but once in some post we had little game like u were posting random account link and i was telling whether that person is male or female . and from that we had talk and this thing was came up. i dont think u would remember that but anyways u are having same profile picture since then so i recognized u :))

Comment: @Neel haha, always good to have a challenge... and I finally found [what you talk about](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/753/discussion-between-neel-and-shadow-wizard) - wow, time fly by! (that said, maybe time to update my avatar with a more recent picture... he's almost 2.5 y/o by now ;))

Comment: haha omg u have found that.. i tried to search but could not remember but u have found :))) yeah time fly by...yes update ur kid picture and i remember u have one daughter as well :)) btw just noticed i first thought ur female coz of ur parenting site.. a compliment for u for being awesome parent :))

Comment: Very true @Neel - well, I'm good at searching, years of experience in Meta site do this to you. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="MyLink" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click">Doit</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: last time I checked, you can't post server side using ASP.NET Hyperlink control

Comment: @Nee, thanks, you are right, you have to use a Linkbutton control.   Answer is now fixed.

Comment: I don't wanna to the "DoIt" string be a asp.net control .. It's between <a> tag .

Comment: @Persian, the control will render as an anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

use the LinkButton ASP control to fire that event

```
<asp:LinkButton id="something" onClick="Button1_Click" Text="DoIt" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I don't wanna to the "DoIt" string be a asp.net control .

Comment: What exactly do you want? If you want to make an Ajax call through jQuery in ASP.NET Webforms then you need to following this step by step tutorial > http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ .

Answer (score 0):

To call a server side method on a client side event you need to do the following:

1- Create the server side method:

```
void DoSomething(...) { ... }
```

2- Implement the `System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent` which take one string argument (You can assign the name to the value of this argument).:

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument) 
{
        DoSomething(...);
}
```

3- Write a script to trigger post back:

```
function TriggerPostBack(control, arg){
    __doPostBack(control, arg);
}
```

4- Call the PostBack trigger function when needed:

```
<a .... onclick="TriggerPostBack('control', 'arg')" .. />
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are generating HTML, if you want to invoke from JavaScript use:

```
__doPostBack('<your controls UniqueID>','');
```

But you will need to have an asp control on your page either way...

Comment: Have you an (invisible) "Button1" Control in your page, passing its .UniqueID property as the first argument?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function GO(){
        $("#<%=btnGo.ClientID=%>").click();
    }
</script>

<a id="" href="GO();"">Doit</a>

<asp:Button id="btnGo" onClick="Button1_Click">
```

i didn't test this, but, this is the basic ideia, if you don't wanna use the LinkButton (that is the best option)

PS: If you are using framework 4.0, you can use the clientid static.
PS2: if want, you can hide the button, but again, the best way to do this is with LinkButton.

EDIT: Are you only trying redirect to another page ??? o.O ???